# Obj-C: trying to make simple get request, answer always empty

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to Objective-c. I'm trying to do a simple get request and get the page content as a result but the response is always empty.

Here is my code, what am I doing wrong here?

### main

```
HttpManager* pHttpManager;
pHttpManager  = [[HttpManager alloc] init];
NSURL *myURL = [pHttpManager getUrlContent:@"http://www.wikipedia.org"];
NSError* error = nil;
if(myURL) {
  NSLog(@"NSURL is valid");
  NSLog(@"absoluteString:%@",myURL.absoluteString);
  NSString *myHomePage = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: myURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
  if(myHomePage) {
    NSLog(@"%@", myHomePage);
  } else {
    NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
  }
} else {
  NSLog(@"NSURL with error");
}
```

### HttpManager Class

```
@implementation HttpManager
-(NSURL*) getUrlContent:(NSString*) url {
  NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
  return myURL;
}
```

### The Error:

> $ ./obj/simple_app.exe
>   2013-01-13 10:15:06.400 simple_app[7656] NSURL is valid
>   2013-01-13 10:15:06.406 simple_app[7656] absoluteString:http://www.wikipedia.org
>   2013-01-13 10:15:07.383 simple_app[7656] unable to set blocking mode - An invalid argument was supplied.
>   2013-01-13 10:15:07.398 simple_app[7656] Error = NSCocoaErrorDomain 259

Comment: If have found the error message "unable to set blocking mode" in the source code of the GNUStep library (http://searchco.de/codesearch/view/20212689). Are you using that?

Comment: Since his program name is "./obj/simple_app.exe" then, yes, maybe it's GNUStep on Windows? Hey @user63898, why would you not mention such an important detail?

Comment: hu right using GNUSetup , sorry

Comment: So the real cause for this error could be that GNUStep does not implement `stringWithContentsOfURL: encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding` correctly, perhaps causing some memory corruption. But in any case, using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` as in Kurt's answer is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally one would do this:

```
NSString *myHomePage = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: myURL
                        encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

What happens when you try that? (And why did you use `NSASCIIStringEncoding` in the first place?)

The web page at `http://www.wikipedia.org` contains [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters that cannot be represented in the [ASCII encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), but can be represented in the (far more modern) [UTF-8 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8). There is rarely any reason to use ASCII anymore unless you are working with very old data.

Comment: working !! can you please explain why ? ( im new to objC)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Objective-C, really. Edited answer to add more information.

Comment: Reading the contents of www.wikipedia.org with NSASCIIStringEncoding does not fail (I have tried it). It is not the right thing to do, but it returns a string and not an error. There must be something else ...

Comment: @MartinR: agreed, works for me too.